# A variant of infinitary equivalence

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be the language consisting of a single binary relation symbol, $R$ (so $\Sigma$-structures are graphs, in the model theory sense). For a logic $\mathcal{L}$, say that an **$\mathcal{L}$-similarity notion** is an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\varphi$ in a finite relational language $\Sigma'$ containing at least $\Sigma$ and two unary relation symbols $X,Y$ which is **elementarity-refining:**

> For all $\Sigma$-structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$, if there is an $\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$ with $X^\mathcal{M}\upharpoonright\Sigma\cong\mathcal{A}$ and $Y^\mathcal{M}\upharpoonright\Sigma\cong\mathcal{B}$ then $\mathcal{A}\equiv_{\mathcal{L}}\mathcal{B}$.

For $\varphi$ an $\mathcal{L}$-similarity notion and $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ structures such that an $\mathcal{M}$ of the above type exists, write "$\mathcal{A}\sim_\varphi\mathcal{B}$."

Each logic $\mathcal{L}$ then gives rise to an equivalence relation $\approx_\mathcal{L}$ refining its elementary equivalence relation $\equiv_\mathcal{L}$: take the smallest equivalence relation containing the set of pairs $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ with $\mathcal{A}\sim_\varphi\mathcal{B}$ for some $\mathcal{L}$-similarity notion $\varphi$. *(This is usually redudnant - for reasonably nice logics that set of pairs is already an equivalence relation - but meh.)*

Now for some logics this is boring - for example, when $\mathcal{L}$ is either $\mathsf{FOL}$ or $\mathsf{SOL}$ we get ${\approx_\mathcal{L}}={\equiv_\mathcal{L}}$ by [Fraisse's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game#Equivalence_and_inexpressibility), the $\mathsf{SOL}$ case also involving a bit of cheating - but for infinitary logics the situation seems more complicated. Specifically, it seems plausible based on [an argument of Farmer S.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414083/can-mathcall-omega-1-omega-detect-mathcall-omega-1-omega-equiv?noredirect=1&lq=1) that $\approx_{\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}}$ (or just $\approx_{\omega_1,\omega}$ more simply) is **strictly finer** than $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$.

> Is $\approx_{\omega_1,\omega}$ in fact strictly finer than $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$? If so, is there any snappy description of it (e.g. is it $\equiv_\mathcal{L}$ for some "nice" logic $\mathcal{L}$)?

One quick observation is that if $\eta$ is a *complete* $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence then "Either $f$ is an isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ or both $X$ and $Y$ satisfy $\eta$" (construed appropriately) is an $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-similarity notion; consequently, whenever $Th_{\omega_1,\omega}(\mathcal{A})$ is axiomatized by a single $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence we have $[\mathcal{A}]_{\approx_{\omega_1,\omega}}=[\mathcal{A}]_{\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}}$. In particular, if $\approx_{\omega_1,\omega}$ is different from $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$ we won't see this at the level of countable models by Scott's Isomorphism Theorem.

---

**Embarrassing admission**

An early version of this question looked at the "elementarity-*coarsening*" analogous notion. But this was silly: as long as $\mathcal{L}$ is a "reasonable" logic (and $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ certainly qualifies) we can form sentences of the form $\varphi^X\leftrightarrow\varphi^Y$ for each $\varphi\in\mathcal{L}$, and these give rise to a family of equivalence relations individually coarsening $\equiv_\mathcal{L}$ whose intersection is exactly $\equiv_\mathcal{L}$. So that was not my finest moment. The refining situation, however, seems less trivial (for now ...).