# Is this approximation to infinitary equivalence coarse on countable structures?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, descriptive-set-theory

*This question is a kind of dual to [this earlier one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415596/). Note that if we replace $\mathsf{FOL}$ with $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$, things trivialize since we can use the theory $\{\varphi^A\leftrightarrow\varphi^B: \varphi\in\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}\}$. The situation would also trivialize if we replaced $\mathsf{FOL}$ with $\mathsf{SOL}$, but not trivially: the point is that the game characterization by [Vaananen and Wang](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0108.pdf) is appropriately second-order expressible. Throughout, all signatures are finite.*

Fix two unary relation symbols $A,B$ and a binary relation symbol $E$ (I'll call $\{E\}$-structures "graphs" for simplicity). For every **first-order** theory $T$ in a language $\supseteq\{A,B,E\}$, let $\sim_T$ be the relation on graphs given by $$\mathfrak{A}\sim_T\mathfrak{B}\quad\iff\quad\exists\mathfrak{M}\models T(A^\mathfrak{M}\upharpoonright\{E\}\cong\mathfrak{A}\wedge B^\mathfrak{M}\upharpoonright\{E\}\cong\mathfrak{B}).$$

Letting $\sim$ be the intersection of all $\sim_T$s which are equivalence relations coarsening $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$, we get that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on graphs which is isomorphism-invariant and (by a [result of Farmer S.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414179/8133)) strictly coarsens $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$ on graphs in general.

> **Question**: Is $\sim$ strictly coarser than $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$ (or equivalently, $\cong$) on *countable* graphs?

That is, are there non-isomorphic countable graphs which are $\sim$-equivalent? Note that the obvious theory describing an isomorphism (or even potential isomorphism) between the $A$- and $B$-parts does not satisfy the $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$-coarsening property.

Comment: Does the notation $A^M\upharpoonright\{E\}$ mean the structure $(A^M,E\upharpoonright A^M)$, i.e. with universe $A^M$ and binary relation the restriction of $E=E^M$ to this set?

Comment: @FarmerS Yes, that's right.

Comment: I don't see why $\sim_T$ is an equivalence relation. What if e.g. $T$ satisfies "$A\neq\emptyset=B$"? Isn't $\sim_T$ then non-reflexive?

Comment: @FarmerS That's not $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$-invariant; $\sim$ is just the intersection of the $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$-invariant $\sim_T$s.

Comment: (@FarmerS But I did forget to add transitivity. Now fixed!)

Comment: By "$\sim_T$ is $\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$-invariant", do you mean that whenever $A\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}A'$ and $B\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}B'$ then $A\sim_T B$ iff $A'\sim_T B'$?

Comment: @FarmerS No, I meant just $\sim_T\supseteq\equiv_{\omega_1,\omega}$ - in retrospect I see that was a very bad phrasing. Fixing ...

Comment: And I think the "$C$" in the middle should be an "$E$", is that right? (Also, although in the end you restrict the kinds of $T$s you consider, initially it talks about an arbitrary $T$, and says that $\sim_T$ is an equivalence relation there.)

Comment: Is $T$ allowed to use other symbols beyond $A,B,E$?

Comment: @FarmerS Oh yes, the $C$ should be an $E$. Fixing (this has not been my best question success!) ...