# Fragments of infinitary logic with a weak definability property

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, computability-theory

For a countable admissible ordinal $\alpha$, let $\mathcal{L}_\alpha=\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}\cap L_\alpha$ and let $\equiv_\alpha$ be the corresponding elementary equivalence relation. Say that such an $\alpha$ is **locally Fraissean** iff there is an $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$-sentence $\eta$ in the language $\{R,S,A,B\}$, with $R,S$ binary relation symbols and $A,B$ unary relation symbols, such that for every pair of $\{R\}$-structures $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}\in L_\alpha$ we have $$\mathcal{X}\equiv_\alpha\mathcal{Y}\quad\iff\quad\exists\mathcal{M}\in L_\alpha[\mathcal{M}\models\eta\wedge (A^\mathcal{M}\cong\mathcal{X}\wedge B^\mathcal{M}\cong\mathcal{Y})^{L_\alpha}]$$ (the $L_\alpha$-superscript meaning that relevant isomorphisms have to exist within $L_\alpha$ itself).

For example, if $\equiv_\alpha$ coincides with $\cong$ on $\{R\}$-structures in $L_\alpha$, then $\alpha$ is locally Fraissean; in particular, if $L_\alpha\equiv L_{\omega_1}$ then $\alpha$ is locally Fraissean. But this seems like overkill:

> What is the smallest locally Fraissean ordinal?

It's already not clear to me whether $\omega_1^{CK}$ is locally Fraissean - in particular, the argument [Farmer S. gave](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414179/8133) that $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ doesn't satisfy the "global" version of the property above doesn't seem to trivially effectivize (although I could be missing something).

Comment: About "$\mathcal{L}_\alpha=\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}\cap L_\alpha$", what is $L_\alpha$ here, if it's the $\alpha$th level of the constructible hierarchy then how do we intersect it with a language?

Comment: @C7X Remember that everything, in the ZFC context, is a set; this includes $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$-formulas. You can find more details in Barwise's book [*Admissible sets and structures*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Admissible-Sets-and-Structures-An-Approach-to-Definability-Theory/toc/pl/1235418470) (this is a crucial notion throughout, e.g. in his completeness/compactness theorems).

Comment: @C7X (Forgot to finish my comment!) So $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}\cap L_\alpha$ (with $L_\alpha$ being the $\alpha$th level of the constructible hierarchy as usual) does parse, although it looks weird at first. A big component of Barwise's research on infinitary logic is that, even though $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ itself is a bit wild, its "countable fragments" (the $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$s) are surprisingly tame. (Incidentally, there is a difference between $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}\cap L_\alpha$ and $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}\cap L_\alpha$ even when $\alpha$ is countable: (contd)

Comment: formulas in the latter set are "explicitly countable," while formulas in the former are not. $L_\alpha$ may not be able to "see" that $\varphi\in\mathcal{L}_\alpha$ is in fact equivalent to an $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-formula. This usually isn't a big deal, but sometimes matters. See [here](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Admissible-Sets-and-Structures-An-Approach-to-Definability-Theory/Chapter/Chapter-III-Countable-Fragments-of-mathsfL_inftyomega/pl/1235418475).)

Comment: I think we can always use $M$ such that $A^M=X$ and $B^M=Y$. Let $\mathcal{L}_\alpha(Z)$ be the set of $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$-formulae in the language $Z$, and for let $\equiv_\alpha$ be elementary equivalence for formulae in $\mathcal{L}_\alpha(\{R\})$. Then that means $\alpha$ is locally Fraissean iff there's a formula $\eta\in\mathcal{L}_\alpha(\{R,S,A,B\})$ such that $(M\models\eta)\iff(A^M\equiv_\alpha B^M)$

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add "for $M\in L_\alpha$" at the end. Looks like i can't edit my comment. Anyway, this should simplify the question a lot, although i'm not used to working with languages so i still can't answer it.

Comment: @Yto We definitely **don't** want $M\models\eta$ to always be equivalent to $A^M\equiv_\alpha B^M$; some ways of building a $\{R,S,A,B\}$-structure around the two input structures will just not be informative. The existential quantifier over $M$ is crucial.

Comment: If you want, though, you could instead phrase it as: there is some $\{A,B,R,S\}$-sentence $\eta$ such that $(i)$ whenever $M\models\eta$ we have $A^M\equiv_\alpha B^M$ and $(ii)$ for every $X\equiv_\alpha Y$ there is some $M\models \eta$ with $A^M\cong X$ and $B^M\cong Y$. But again, there's a crucial existential quantification in play.

Comment: Note that all admissible $\alpha$ s.t. $L_\alpha\models \Pi_1\textsf{-Sep}+\forall x (|x|\le |\omega|)$ will be locally Fraissean. Indeed, for such $\alpha$'s, Scott sentences for all $R$-structures $\mathcal{X}\in L_\alpha$ are in $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}\cap L_\alpha$ and for any isomorphic $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}\in L_\alpha$ there is an isomorphism from $L_\alpha$. That is for any  $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}\in L_\alpha$ we have $\mathcal{X}\equiv_\alpha\mathcal{Y}$ iff $L_\alpha$ thinks that they are isomorphic. Hence $\eta$ could simply express that the structures are isomorphic.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov That's true; however, it's not clear to me that we can't go even lower, with a more complicated $\eta$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber After I wrote the previous comment I figured out that the same $\eta$ in fact would work for all internally countable recursively inaccessible ordinals. Essentially it follows from formalization in KP of Theorem 1.3 from Nadel, Mark. "Scott sentences and admissible sets." Annals of Mathematical Logic 7.2-3 (1974): 267-294.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  I am almost sure that the answer to your question is that the first recursively inaccessible ordinal is the least locally Fraissean ordinal. I guess that one could show that smaller admissibles $\alpha$ aren't locally Fraissean by proving $\Pi_1$-completeness in $L_\alpha$ of $\equiv_\alpha$ using some uniform construction of Harrison style orders (the orders corresponding to true $\Pi_1$ sentences should have order types $\alpha(1+\mathbb{Q})$ and the orders corresponding to false sentences should have smaller well-ordered parts). Although I haven't worked this out.